# VScode extension: how can I add custom UI *inside* the editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm building a vscode extension, and I want to add custom UI on/below the active line.

I saw a similar UI in copilot chat demo video.

[image: copilot chat screenshot]

The UI is custom, and spans lines, so it doesn't look like CodeLens, CodeAction, or Decorations.

I tried to create webview, but that always renders on a new tab.

Comment: search the extension source code for the text string you can read

Comment: it might be a variation of the peek windows, AFAIK extensions can't construct peek windows

Comment: AFAIK, copilot chat extension is not open source... so I couldn't read the source code.
Is there a thing called peek window? I don't see it on https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api. are you talking about codeLens (then, yeah, I don't think it allow custom UI in it)?

Comment: peek window is the feature shown when you ask **Show References** or **Show Definition**, it is a small editor window to some other file that sometimes is also editable

Comment: Codepilot is not running some binary stuff in the VSC GUI, maybe the code is minified but you can reformat the code and search for the string, the vsix file is just a zip file

Answer (score 3):

Okay, nevermind. It's not available in public API (at least now - July 2023).

I found the feature request ticket https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85682

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).